# $(A^x) \mathbin\% p = (A^{x \mathbin\% (p - 1)}) % p$ if $p$ is prime. Is this true when $A$ is a matrix?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, matrix-equations

$(A^x) \mathbin\% p = (A^{x \mathbin\% (p - 1)}) % p$ if $p$ is prime.

Is this property true when $A$ is a matrix?

Suppose $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 &1\\
1 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0
\end{pmatrix},$$
$x=1000000007$ and $p=1000000007$

Then
$$( A^X ) \mathbin\% p =
\begin{pmatrix}
097981108 & 432592815 & 646971665\\
646971665 & 451009450 & 432592815 \\
432592815 & 214378850 & 451009450
\end{pmatrix}$$

But $(A^1)\mathbin\%p$ **[ as,$ ( x \mathbin\% (p-1) )=1 $ ]** is the same matrix.

Comment: What does $(A^x)\mathbin\%p$ mean when $A$ is a matrix?

Comment: While doing multiplication, the result of each cell, will be calculated Modulo P.

Comment: Is there any indication that this would hold? For example, it heavily relies on a choice of representatives for $\mod p$ and $\mod p-1$. If $x = 2, p = 3$, we get the rather surprising assertion that any matrix squared is, modulo 3, equal to the identity matrix.

Comment: Although the OP's assertion is not itself true, it raises an interesting question:  to what extent might a version of Fermat's Little Theorem hold for matrices?  Apparently V.I. Arnold worked on this problem quite a bit!  See http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/fermats-little-theorem-for-matrices/ ,

Comment: Most certainly not true when $p=2\>$(!) Besides that, you’re trying out a conjecture first with a huge prime, when you should first try out many examples with small primes.

Answer (score 1):

As Lord Farin points out, this is certainly false. Consider for example any prime $p$ and the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
which satisfies $A^x=0$ for all $x>1$.